# Esper detect events dissimilar to previous events in a sliding time window

Tags: esper

I am trying to write an EPStatement that will match any event that does not have a specified field "similar" to another event in a sliding time window. For example only match events where "value" is at least distance 3 from any other event in the sliding window,

```
At t=t_0, E0={value=0}  // Match
At t=t_1, E1={value=9}  // Match
At t=t_2, E2={value=1}  // Don't match since value is within 3 of E0.value
```

I am looking for a statement where I could use any expression that compares two values as the "similarity" metric. I looked at using [patterns](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.0.0-beta2/reference-esper/html/event_patterns.html) or [match recognize](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.0.0-beta2/reference-esper/html/event_patterns.html) but they don't seem to support this type of dynamic comparison to an unknown number of previous events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from SomeEvent#keepall as e 
having not window(*).anyOf(p => Math.abs(p.value - e.value) <= 3 and p.id != e.id)
```

The `window(*)` holds all events. The `anyOf` goes thru the window to find any that match. The `p.id=e.id` excludes the current event. field `id` being a unique id of the event that you may or may not have as an event property on the event.